# Сохранение окна с его виджетами PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

не получается сохранить настройки после выхода

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QCheckBox, QApplication,QAction
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QSettings
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import pickle

CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'

class Central_Widget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):


        self.input=QtWidgets.QLineEdit("Введите задание",self)
        self.input.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial",12))
        self.input.resize(self.input.width()+140,self.input.height())
        self.add_task_but=QtWidgets.QPushButton("Добавить",self)
        self.add_task_but.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial",12))
        self.vrl=QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.im=QtGui.QPixmap()
        self.im.load("weather/x.png")
        self.vlayout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.vrl)
        self.setGeometry(0,30,700,500)
        self.input.move(150,40)
        self.input.setMaximumWidth(600)
        self.add_task_but.move(self.input.x()+self.input.width(),self.input.y()-1)
        self.add_task_but.resize(self.add_task_but.width(),self.input.height()+2)
        self.vrl.setGeometry(self.input.x()-20,self.input.y()+30, 500, 50)
        self.setWindowTitle('Список Дел')
        self.add_task_but.clicked.connect(self.push_on_add_task_but)
        #self.show()

    def changeFont(self, state):
        temp = QtGui.QFont("Arial", 12)
        if state == Qt.Checked:
            temp.setStrikeOut(True)
        else:
            temp.setStrikeOut(False)
        self.sender().setFont(temp)


    def push_on_add_task_but(self):
        if (self.height()-self.vrl.height())<=60:
            self.resize(self.width(),self.height()+90)
        del_but = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        del_but.resize(self.im.size())
        del_but.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.im))
        del_but.setFixedSize(20,20)
        temp_hrl=QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        temp=QCheckBox(self.input.text())
        temp.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial",12))
        temp.stateChanged.connect(self.changeFont)
        temp_hrl.addWidget(temp)
        temp_hrl.addWidget(del_but)
        self.vlayout.addLayout(temp_hrl)
        del_but.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_del_but)
        self.vrl.resize(self.vrl.width(),self.vrl.height()+self.input.height())
        self.input.clear()




    def on_clicked_del_but(self):
        for j in range(self.vlayout.count()):
            temp_h_l =self.vlayout.itemAt(j)
            if self.sender()==temp_h_l.itemAt(1).widget():
                temp_h_l.itemAt(0).widget().hide()
                temp_h_l.itemAt(1).widget().hide()
                self.vlayout.removeItem(self.vlayout.itemAt(j))
                self.vrl.resize(self.vrl.width(), self.vrl.height()-self.input.height())
                break

class Mainwidge(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.Scroll_W=QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.main_widget=Central_Widget()
        self.Scroll_W.resize(self.main_widget.size())
        self.Scroll_W.setWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.Scroll_W)
        self.resize(self.centralWidget().width(),self.centralWidget().height())
        self.setWindowTitle(self.main_widget.windowTitle())
        self.menu=self.menuBar()
        self.filemenu= self.menu.addMenu("&Файл")
        saveAction = QAction(QtGui.QIcon('weather/file.png'), '&Сохранить', self)
        self.filemenu.addAction(saveAction)
        saveAction.triggered.connect(self.save_file)
        self.load_settings()
        self.show()





    def save_file(self):

        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue('WindowState', self.saveState())
        settings.setValue('Central_widget', self.centralWidget())


    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)


        state = settings.value('WindowState')
        if state:
            self.restoreState(state)

        cenral=settings.value('Central_widget')
        if cenral:
            self.setCentralWidget(cenral)

        # self.cb_flag.setChecked(settings.value('BoolValue', 'false') == 'true')






if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Mainwidge()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/Valvea/PyQT/blob/master/to_do_list/todolist.py

Исправленная версия,если кому-нибудь еще понадобится для обучения

Comment: Работает, но обратите внимание на то, что писал @gil9red `А сохранение настроек принято вызывать в событии closeEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю [пример сохранения и загрузки настроек](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5a0176269d6a59e9dde05f1555eddabe07a91d01/opencv__Color_Detection_Tool/main.py#L269) окна через `QSettings`:

Создание хранилища:

```
settings = QSettings("config.ini", QSettings.IniFormat)
```

Установка значения:

```
settings.setValue(<название поля>, <значение>)
```

Получение значения:

```
settings.value(<название поля>)
```

---

Загрузку настроек можно вызывать в конструкторе окна, можно из вне - например после создания и показа окна.

А сохранение настроек принято вызывать в событии `closeEvent`

---

У виджетов-окон, кстати, есть методы для сохранения и восстановления размера окна и положения на экране: [saveGeometry](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#saveGeometry) и [restoreGeometry](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#restoreGeometry). А у [QMainWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html), дополнительно есть еще методы [saveState](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#saveState) и [restoreState](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#restoreState), которые сохраняют и восстановливают состояние `QToolBar` и `QDockWidget` окна.

---

Теперь код:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QSettings, QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QCheckBox, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        self.cb_flag = QCheckBox()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.cb_flag)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.load_settings()

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)

        settings.setValue('Geometry', self.saveGeometry())
        settings.setValue('WindowState', self.saveState())

        settings.setValue('StrValue', self.line_edit.text())
        settings.setValue('BoolValue', int(self.cb_flag.isChecked()))
        # settings.setValue('BoolValue', 'true' if self.cb_flag.isChecked() else 'false')

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)

        geometry = settings.value('Geometry')
        if geometry:
            self.restoreGeometry(geometry)

        state = settings.value('WindowState')
        if state:
            self.restoreState(state)

        self.line_edit.setText(settings.value('StrValue', ""))
        self.cb_flag.setChecked(bool(int(settings.value('BoolValue', 0))))
        # self.cb_flag.setChecked(settings.value('BoolValue', 'false') == 'true')

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        self.save_settings()
        super().closeEvent(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Не получатся восстановить значение

Comment: @Valvea, в моем примере или в вашем? :)

Comment: А как сдедаьб чтобы мой центральный видежет сохранился?

Comment: @Valvea, из коробки это не сделать -- нужно будет для Central_Widget писать методы (де)сериализации и в MainWindow.load_settings и MainWindow.save_settings у объекта `self.main_widget` дергать его методы. Ваша задача немного специфичная и для нее я бы данные не в ini хранил, а в json, или на крайний случай в xml. Создайте новый вопрос с вашим кодом и сюда ссылку добавьте. Я бы и тут ответил, но ответ уже был дан на изначальный вопрос, а переделывание его будет значительным :)

Comment: я выкрутился так                    l

Comment: @Valvea, молодец что сами справились :)